# Silverlight 5 PivotViewer control rendering locally on server but not remotely

Tags: silverlight, iis-6, silverlight-5.0, pivotviewer

I have deployed a Silverlight 5 PivotViewer web app that runs successfully on the development machine to a server running IIS 6.0.
On that server, the application in a browser runs successfully from localhost.  If, on the server, I browse to the html file directly, I get a blank pivotviewer control rendered (as if it can't find my cxml file)
Remotely, I get the same response, a blank pivotviewer control loads.  I can access the cxml file remotely via http.  However, for one reason or another, the pivotviewer comes up empty.
Please help!

Comment: What is coming back from the CxmlCollectionSource when it loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the CXML, DZI and DZC MIME type to your webserver :

```
appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.cxml',mimeType='text/xml']

appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.dzc',mimeType='text/xml']

appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+[fileExtension='.dzi',mimeType='text/xml']
```